# Identify duplicate files from leading number of characters

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I have a file directory which contains approx. 600 employee image files which have been copied from an alternative source.

The filename format is:

```
xxxxxx_123456_123_20141212.jpg
```

When the employee image file is updated it just creates another file in the same location and only the `datetime` changes at the end.

I need to be able to identify the most recent file, however i need to establish first of all which files are 'duplicated'.

My initial thoughts were to try and match the first 14 characters and, if they matched, work out the recent modified date and then delete the older file.

Comment: please post what you have tried allready and describe what errors you get and what the expected outcome of the code is.

Comment: I have tried multiple methods, no errors it just isn't doing what i want and i can't seem to find the correct syntax to even begin to try and troubleshoot it. An example of what i would like to achieve is where there are 2 files  (amongst the 600) File1: xxxxxx_123456_123_20141212.jpg and File2: xxxxxx_123456_123_20150101.jpg i'm only interested in File2 and want to remove file1. I already have some powershell ready to rename the files but i can't use it as it states the file already exists so i need to remove the oldest file before i can rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires PowerShell version 3.

```
$Path = 'C:\Users\madtomvane\Documents\PowerShellTest'
           #Get the files                        #Group them by name                          #Select the most resent file
$FilesToKeep = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -File | Group-Object -Property {$_.Name[0..14]} | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1}

              #Get the files                          #Group them by name                    #Where there is more than one file in the group                            #Select the old ones
$FilesToRemove = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -File | Group-Object -Property {$_.Name[0..14]} | Where-Object {$_.Group.Count -gt 1} | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1}
$FilesToRemove | Remove-Item
```